# How to pass parameters into a SPARQL query

Tags: c#, sparql, dotnetrdf

How do I pass var1 and var2 into the sparql query shown below. I have the code below but its not returning anything.

I appreciate your help on this. Thank you in adavnce

```
string var1, var2;
var1 = DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString();
var2 = DropDownList2.SelectedValue.ToString();
//Load first listbox
private const string loadlist1 = @"
                     PREFIX au: <http://semwebowl.somee.com/au/n3_notation#>
                                    SELECT DISTINCT ?ResearchArea 

                                    WHERE {
                                        [a  au:var1;
                                            au:ResearchArea var2;
                                            au:ResearchArea ?ResearchArea].
                                            }";
```

Comment: You may want to check the SPARQL query - it's missing the subject in the triple pattern

Comment: You should do some research effort before asking. A quick search shows how to pass parameters into SPARQL queries: http://www.dotnetrdf.org/api/dotNetRDF~VDS.RDF.Query.SparqlParameterizedString.html

Comment: Hi I tried dotnetrdf docs but no luck. I am parsing an ontology notation 3 file using sparql query above. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you actually try to do as the link (in my comment above) says? If yes, what was the result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solve the problem by separating it into 2 parts:

1. Check that your SPARQL query is correct. Make sure that it works OK when you put the correct values directy in the query text. Like @scotthenninger said your query appears to be invalid.
2. Pass parameters into the SPARQL query (see [DotNetRDF API docs](http://www.dotnetrdf.org/api/dotNetRDF~VDS.RDF.Query.SparqlParameterizedString.html)). The method to use will depend on if it is a URI (`.SetUri()`) or text value. Use the `.ToString()` method on the parametrized SPARQL string to check what it looks like once variable values are inserted into the string.